# Webflux returning cors error on Access denied

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux, webflux

```
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http,
            ReactiveAuthenticationManager jwtAuthenticationManager,
            ServerAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter
    ) {

        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(jwtAuthenticationManager);
        authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);

        return http
                .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .securityMatcher(
                        new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                                new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(ALLOWED_URLS.toArray(new String[0])),
                                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                                )
                        )
                )
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .logout()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, e) -> {
                    if (e.getCause() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                        throw new ForbiddenException(e);
                    }
                    throw new UnauthorizedException(e);
                })
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/api/auth/password").hasAnyRole(RolesList.SUPER_ADMIN.name(), RolesList.ADMIN.name())
                .pathMatchers("/api/client/**").hasRole(RolesList.SUPER_ADMIN.name())
                .pathMatchers("/api/user/**").hasRole(RolesList.SUPER_ADMIN.name())
                .pathMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() //entire server side app will be kept here
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CorsGlobalConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    private final NetworkProperties networkProperties;

    public CorsGlobalConfiguration(NetworkProperties networkProperties) {
        this.networkProperties = networkProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/client/search")
                .allowedOrigins(networkProperties.getAllowedOrigins())
                .allowedMethods("POST", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

Above are my spring security config and cors config.
When super admin accessing /api/client/search he is getting success response.
But when admin is trying to access he is getting Cors error instead of access denied.

What am i missing here?

Below is the exception stack trace which very strange according to exception my exception handler is creating response but browser displaying cors error instead of Access denined.

Again same thing is working fine for super admin

```
com.adminpanel.api.common.exceptions.ForbiddenException: Forbidden
    at com.adminpanel.api.auth.config.SecurityConfig.lambda$securityWebFilterChain$0(SecurityConfig.java:81)
    Suppressed: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$1(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53)
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
Stack trace:
            at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$1(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:99)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:77)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:93)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoAny$AnySubscriber.onComplete(MonoAny.java:130)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:334)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:679)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFlattenIterable.java:260)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:165)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:336)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:384)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1795)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2393)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
            at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:481)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:414)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:364)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
            at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
            at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:262)
            at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1813)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:320)
            at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:337)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
            at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:249)
            at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
            at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/api/client/search" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at com.adminpanel.api.auth.config.SecurityConfig.lambda$securityWebFilterChain$0(SecurityConfig.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.commenceAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:72)
        at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.lambda$filter$1(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:44)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$31(Mono.java:3401)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2059)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2059)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:196)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:77)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:93)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoAny$AnySubscriber.onComplete(MonoAny.java:130)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:334)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:679)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFlattenIterable.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:165)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:336)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:384)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1795)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2393)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:481)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:414)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:364)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:262)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1813)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:320)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:337)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:249)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: Not Authenticated
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.commenceAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.lambda$filter$1(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$31(Mono.java:3401)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:390)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2059)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2059)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:196)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:77)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:93)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoAny$AnySubscriber.onComplete(MonoAny.java:130)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:334)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:679)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFlattenIterable.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:336)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:384)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1795)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2393)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:481)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:414)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:364)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4252)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1812)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:262)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1813)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:320)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:337)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:249)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied]
```